# Different line breaks with pdflatex and latex-dvips-ps2pdf

Tags: pdftex, dvips, ps2pdf

I have noticed that, for the same text, I get slightly different line breaks depending on whether I use `pdflatex` or a `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence. This is what I get with `pdflatex`

[image]

And this is what I get with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`

[image]

This is not a problem that requires a solution. I'm just trying to understand how `pdflatex` and `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` differ, such that each handles line breaks differently.

Comment: I have never seen that happen. Are you using microtype that has some features that are still (I think) only implemented for pdf output

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's because of microtype. Once I comment it out, I get the second output with `pdflatex` as well.

Comment: This is one more example of how useful it is to provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default linebreaking code is the same in pdflatex and latex, so normally you get identical breaks if using the same fonts, however the `microtype` package has some options that only work for pdf output so you can get different behaviour depending on the options used (which you don't show).